# How to scroll the parent div when hovering on a child div and scrolling?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I've been trying to figure out a way to do this stuff. What I want to do is to scroll the parent div (which has a scrollbar) when hovering an inner Div and scrolling.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/FdeAR/

Comment: You want to scroll down on the larger `div` when you `hover` over the smaller `div` - is that correct ?

Comment: He wants to be able to scroll as if he wasn't holding the mouse over the smaller div, based on the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following (Guessing from your requirement);

http://jsfiddle.net/FdeAR/23/

Basically bind a mousewheel event to the smaller div and scroll it up/down based on the direction of the mousewheel determined by the delta

```
$(function () {
    $('div:last').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        var direction = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0 ? '-' : '+';
        $('div:first').animate({'scrollTop': direction + '=20px'}, 10);
    });
});​
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. It worked for this example but does not work for iframe having pdf in it. Take a look at it please:  http://jsfiddle.net/FdeAR/24/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FdeAR/29/ That's because your iframe is scrolled along with the div